# How to resolve a error in as_mapper(.f...) missing an ".f" in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, error-handling, package, maps

```
library(maps)
library(geosphere)
library(dplyr)
map('world',
      col="#b3b3b3", fill=TRUE, bg="white", lwd=0.05,
      mar=rep(0,4),border=0, ylim=c(-80,80) 
      )
points(x=cldrd$longitude, y=cldrd$latitude, col=c("magenta"), cex=(.7), pch=16)    
points(x=outlrd$longitude, y=outlrd$latitude, col=c("black"), cex=(.2), pch=16)
```

> Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : argument ".f" is missing, with no default

> Error in plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...) :
> plot.new has not been called yet

I have run this code previously without error and but restarted R and I am unsure why I keep receiving these particular errors. How do I resolve this error?

Comment: Did you also load the `purr` package? It seems you are using the wrong `map()` function. try `maps::map()` rather than just `map()`. You can check which packages are loaded and in which order with `names(sessionInfo()$otherPkgs)`

Comment: I tried adding >maps:: map to the code and it worked! thanks!